# Java 8 Array List Returns a List of Superclass Objects

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible for an ArrayList to return a list of superclass objects?

For example:

Class B extends Class A.

I have an ArrayList of Class B.

How do I use Java 8 to return an ArrayList of objects of Class A?

Eg:

```
class ClassA {}
class ClassB extends ClassA{}
```

I have a list of ClassB called classBList. I want to get a list of ClassA objects.

```
List <ClassA> classAList = new ArrayList <ClassA> (classBList);
```

But I am still getting ClassB in classAList.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You already have one; a list of B objects is a list of A objects, because all B objects are A objects. Perhaps you could edit the question to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, ideally with a code example.

Comment: Edited. Is it possible?

Comment: Unless `ClassA implements List<ClassA>` then `ClassA` is certainly not assignable to `List<ClassA>`. But this isn't enough code for me to work out what you're trying to do; please write a minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As long as you don't expect a client to add something to the list after calling the method your're working on, you can declare it as `public List<? extends ClassA> body()`, which allows returning a `List<ClassB>`.

Comment: I have edited with codes. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a list of objects of runtime type ClassB and want a list of objects of runtime type ClassA.

Consider:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
ClassA a = b
```

Here `b` and `a` refers to the same instance. An instance of `ClassB`.

If we really wanted to change the runtime type, we'd need to create a new object. Assuming an appropriate constructor:

```
ClassA b = new ClassB();
ClassA a = new ClassA(a);
```

To apply that to a list, I think:

```
List<ClassA> as = bs.stream()
    .map(ClassA::new)
    .toCollection(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Or, more readably but less impressively:

```
List<ClassA> as = new ArrayList<>() {
for (ClassB b : bs) {
    as.add(new ClassA(b);
}
```

However, in general **a class should be either a leaf (effectively final) or abstract**.